# Counting choice streaks in Python

Tags: python, count

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
Subject | Session | Trial | Choice
--------+---------+-------+-------
1       | 1       | 1     | A
1       | 1       | 2     | B
1       | 1       | 3     | B
1       | 1       | 4     | B
1       | 1       | 5     | B
1       | 1       | 6     | A
2       | 1       | 1     | A
2       | 1       | 2     | A
2       | 1       | 3     | A
```

I would like to use a Python script to generate the following table:

```
Subject | Session | streak_count
--------+---------+-------------
1       | 1       | 3
2       | 1       | 1
```

Where `streak_count` is a count of the total number of choice streaks made by a given subject during a given session, and a streak is any number of choices of one particular item in a row (`>0`).

I've tried using some of the suggestions to similar questions here, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to count these instances, rather than measure their length, etc., which seem to be more common queries.

Comment: Please show us the code that you've tried.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the data structure that you're holding your dataset in, but I bet `itertools.groupby` would be useful here.

Comment: Struggling to follow your pattern - why is the result 3 for subject 1 and 1 for subject 2? It seems like subject 2 would have a streak of 2?

Comment: Have you looked at [pandas(http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/10min.html)

Comment: @srig Embarrassingly, I haven't tried any-- I'm such a newbie that I didn't know where to start with this even after reading through as many questions as I could that seemed relevant on SO

Comment: @SteveJ Subject 2 would have a streak count of 1 as there is only one series of the same choice here (three A's in a row); Subject 1 has three streaks (one choice of A, three consecutive choices of B, and one final choice of A). Sorry if that was unclear, hope this improves the clarity of my question.

Comment: @ItayLivni I haven't seen that documentation, thank you for bringing it to my attention. I've been trying to pick up python/pandas through tutorials so this looks much more helpful as a reference.

Comment: @Kevin thank you for suggesting this, I'll have a go at it.

Comment: @MichaelBarrus; I updated my answer based on this new understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for;

```
import itertools

data = [
    [1, 1, 1, 'A'],
    [1, 1, 2, 'B'],
    [1, 1, 3, 'B'],
    [1, 1, 4, 'B'],
    [1, 1, 5, 'B'],
    [1, 1, 6, 'A'],
    [2, 1, 1, 'A'],
    [2, 1, 2, 'A'],
    [2, 1, 3, 'A']
]

grouped = itertools.groupby(data, lambda x: x[0])

results = dict()
this, last = None, None
for key, group in grouped:
    results[key] = 0
    for c, d in enumerate(group):
        this = d
        streak = c == 0 or this[3] != last[3]]
        if streak:
            results[key] += 1
        last = this

print results
```

This yields;

```
{1: 3, 2: 1}
```

Comment: Thank you Steve, I'll update in an hr or two when I get a chance to run this.

Comment: @MichaelBarrus; BTW, I highly recommend you use a good IDE such as PyCharm that will let you step-debug through the code. Being able to see the variables update in real time will help you tremendously as you get started. They have a free, community version (I have no association with JetBrains). Eclipse is another good option.

Comment: Can itertools only be run on matrices? I have my data in a pandas dataframe and I'm getting the following error: 
----> 3 for key, group in grouped:

----> 1 grouped = itertools.groupby('df1', lambda x: x[3])

IndexError: string index out of range (Sorry, this formatting is terrible, not sure how to fix it)

Comment: @MichaelBarrus; Sorry - I don't know anything about pandas. I suspect if you are already using pandas it has its own groupby.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count():
love = []
love1 = []
streak = -1                                
k = 0
session = 1
subject = raw_input("What is your subject? ")
trials = raw_input("How many trials do you wish to do? ")
trial = 0
for i in range(int(trials)):
    choice = raw_input("What was the choice? ")
    love.append(choice)
    love1.append(choice)
    trial += 1
    print subject, trial, choice
    if love[i] == love1[i-1]:
        streak += 1

print subject, session, streak
```

This may be what you want it takes in how many trials you wish to do and whatever your subject is and if there is a streak it adds one. The reason streak starts at -1 is because when you put your first answer it adds one because of the negative index going back to its self.